# UIViews & View Controllers And why is it always...

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller

Why are all the examples dealing with UIViews and there ViewControllers always incorporating a navigation bar, a tab bar, a split view, or a table view?

What is stoping me from creating say three plain UIViews, and three view controllers and using gestures to navigate between the views? Is there an architecture in place that would prevent me from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Techincally nothing prevents you from doing this, and you can always make yout own navigation systems with custom gestures and animations etc. Using the standard way of coding (i. e. with navigation bars, view controllers, etc.) is recommended though if you don't want to make a special UI and just create a standard "iOS-looking" application.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I was wanting to make a simple menu with three buttons that took you to one of the three pages. That is it. So I didn't care to use a navigation bar, tool bar, or anything else that wasn't going to fit the look of the simple app. Thanks again.